using PCA reconstruction to detect outliers
i have a banking customer for whom i am implementing a pilot. It deals with outlier detection in specific accounts. Now the number of transactions in these accounts, on a daily basis, number in their 100's of thousands and the outlier we are looking for is like a needle in a haystack. But apart from other models, i recently stumbled upon reconstruction error of PCA reconstruction as a potential pointer towards outliers. Would the kind folks in the community think this is a good approach

use a first pass on the raw data ( with all the features associated with the transaction ) and perform PCA & use recon error to generate outliers
now aggregate this data using the features, one by one .. for e.g. take the time stamp data and aggregate by "day" OR take the locations and aggregate by "city" AND take MAX val of the transaction ( since adding them is meaningless and using max will help with outlier detection )
now perform step 1 in this data set ( typically FPs that show up at a granular level DONT look like outliers when aggregated ) and find outliers
if the same outlier shows up across all levels then it has the highest probability of being a genuine outlier

again this would be only one of the atleast 3-4 models that will point to the genuine outlier and we would mostly train some basic regression model to assign weights to each of these model outputs
